# composer trying to allocate all the ram pc has

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

when i run `composer require larabook/gateway` in my laravel project in this step :

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
```

it tries to allocate the all 16gb ram i have . and shows the below error :

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.
```

any idea how to fix this because i cant increase the memory usage of composer or php because my system got 16gb of ram . thanks

Comment: Actually it's in byte so it's 1.6GB not 16GB

Comment: Oops . its weird because i increase the memory limit in php.ini so i have to double check that

Answer (score -1):

Try with the following command:-

> COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require larabook/gateway

or set the memory limit in the php.ini file

> memory_limit = -1